# Recovery from SAS Harddrive

Tags: sas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the different widely used RAID levels and when should I consider them?](https://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them)

I have 6 SAS Harddrive configured on RAID 0. One of my SAS Harddrive has gone faulty, So the server is not working. I tried installing windows server 2003 on a SATA harddisk then connected one SAS harddisk but still its not showing. Can anyone please tell me how can i recover my data??

Comment: Unfortunately, RAID 0 offers absolutely no redundancy - the loss of a single drive is the loss of the entire group.  See [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/339128) for further information - to quote from the section on RAID 0: `Good when: Speed at all costs!  Bad when: You care about your data.`  Do you have backups?

Comment: I had backup but it was of earlier one. I needed the current data.

Comment: We understand that you would like to recover the current data. You need to appreciate that the moment RAID 0 was selected for your array, that choice became all but impossible.

Comment: In Array Configuration Utility it shows all the drives, but the logical drive which was there that is not showing.

Answer (score 11):

You have just learned two very important lessons the hard way:

1. **RAID is not a backup** (and RAID 0 is just a way to increase your chance of failure).
2. If you value your data, ***MAKE REGULAR BACKUPS*** and perform frequent restore tests to be sure you can get the data back.

At this point if the failed drive isn't even recognized by your system your options are pretty much limited to sending the drives out to a data recovery company (expect this to be costly).